# Create a loop which extract a column named 'x' in several CSV file and insert the columns in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm trying to create a loop which extract the column named 'x' in several .csv file. Then, I would like to insert those columns in a new data frame.
At this point I've tried the following :

```
path = '/path/to/File/.Csv'
List = os.listdir(path)
data = []

    for tab in List:
        df = 'df_'+tab
        ReadCSV = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/File/' + tab)
        if len(ReadCSV) > 300 :
            data[tab] = ReadCSV[['x']]       
    
    print(data)
```

I do not yet understand why this loop does not work. I have the following error statement in addition :

```
    data[tab] = ReadCSV[['x']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must put an indice (the number of the column minus 1) or a slice (a range of columns)
But don't forget your ReadCSV is a DataFrame.

So try :

```
data[tab] = ReadCSV.x
```

Assuming that the name of the column is the string 'x'